# MySql JSON Schema

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, jsonschema

I have a table in MySql somewhat like this:

```
create table json_docs (
  id int auto_increment primary_key,
  doc json not null
)
```

I also have a json schema that this `doc` column obeys.

```
{
  "$id": "https://my.org/namespace/doc.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {...}
}
```

Is there a way to enforce that schema in MySql during an insert or update?

```
insert into json_docs (doc) values ('{...}')
```

I am also using PHP Laravel. If there is a way to do this in the Model layer of Laravel I would also be interested.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does have json validation support.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-validation-functions.html

Comment: thanks! this is what I was looking for, for some reason I had not found it. too bad this only applies to mysql 8+ _Beginning with MySQL 8.0.17, MySQL supports validation of JSON documents against JSON schemas_

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have any feature built-in to validate JSON documents against a schema.

> Update: This feature now exists in 8.0.17, but prior to that version, the following answer still applies:

You would have to validate your document in your app, independently from inserting it into a database.

See https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema for an open-source JSON validator in PHP.

Comment: Additionally, JSON Schema can be used to represent non flat data, so the schemas being used would need to be flat, and not have multiple layers.

Comment: note: now mysql 8 has that option, see accepted answer

Comment: More on JSON Document Validation with MySQL 8.0.17 at https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/07/json-schema-validation-with-mysql-8017.html